# Lambda function in a time series data and if condition problems

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, lambda, time-series

I need to add a new column of 1 and 0 using the if condition in lambda condition to rules the second one need the previous data series value `df["max_value"]`.

This to write a target column in a time series data for machine learning and i have 2 rules the previous target wasn't 1 and the value of the `df["max_value"]>a` variable called target_percentage
i need to add a new column of 1 and 0 using the if condition in lambda condition to rules the second one need the previous data series value `df["max_value"]`.

```
df["max_value"]=(df["high"].rolling(days_to_target).max().shift(-days_to_target)-df["open"].shift(-1))/df["open"].shift(-1)*100

df["target"]=  df['max_value'].apply(lambda x: 1 if df["max_value"].shift(-1) <target_percentage and x>target_percentage else 0)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What exactly doesn't work in your solution? have you tried something without using apply? I think you can do without it. just try it in two steps. Create a new column filled with a default e.g. `df["max_value"]=0` then do something like `df.loc[(df['max_value'].shift(-1) <target_percentage) &  (df['max_value']>target_percentage), "max_value"]=1` to change the value for all rows which should be 1 rather than 0.

Comment: In your solution I guess for each `apply` call, it would create the shifted dataframe, and that would be a nightmare from performance point of view, so you need to do it somehow, that it is really only done once for the whole dataframe. You surely also could add the shifted column to your dataframe and then call `apply` on the dataframe (instead of the series for column `max_value`). This should also work and is probably a bit closer to what you tried, than what I suggested above, but if you don't want the extra column, its easier to use my first proposal I guess.